# Keeping huge matrix in memory across multiple runs of a C++ program

Tags: c++

I'm writing some C++ code (using the Eigen3 matrix library) to solve a convex optimization problem involving a huge sparse matrix.  It takes a minute or so to read in the matrix from a file, and I don't want to have to read in the matrix from a file every single time I run my program.  (I'm going to be tuning the parameters in my optimization algorithm, which involves running my code many times in a row, and I don't want to have to wait one minute to read in the big matrix each time.)

Is there a way that I can keep this big matrix in memory while I change some parameters in my code then recompile my code and run it again?

This kind of thing is easy in Matlab, but I don't know how it's handled in C++ (although this is a common situation so there must be a standard approach that people take).

Comment: If it's the same matrix can you hard code it?

Comment: You could add a custom build step that writes the matrix to a CPP file and compile that into the executable.

Comment: You could hard-code the data into your program.   Of course, that just means longer compilation times, since the compiler will have to interpret the data every time.    However, matlab will read from a file too.   The real trick is working out a file format that can be read quickly at startup.

Comment: I think the best approach would be: Have a new program that wraps your method and reads the matrix once. Link your approach and pass the matrix to your algorithm the desired number of times.

Comment: Not sure if this possible, can you thread the reading part and split your matrix into multiple files and have a separate thread per splitting up and read them separately simultaneously and combine them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can keep this big matrix in memory while I change some parameters in my code then recompile my code and run it again?

AFAIK keeping the memory of a process while it is not running, and then "rerun" the process is not supported by any operating system.

You could try to:

- improve the reading code for the matrix (or the representation it is stored in, like suggested by chtz).
- keep the matrix loaded by a helper process, and use inter-process communication to work with it from the process containing your "main code"  (which can then be (re)started and stopped at will).
- try to implement some sort of ["hot swapable module"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/221/19963) / hot code reloading.

But most of these will (though fun) be extremely complex to implement.

> I'm going to be tuning the parameters in my optimization algorithm, which involves running my code many times in a row, and I don't want to have to wait one minute to read in the big matrix each time.

How about getting those parameters from user input instead of hard coding them? That would allow you to specify the parameters, run your code, read in another set of parameters, do another run, ... without having to recompile your program or stop and restart the process.

Comment: So far it sounds to me like your last suggestion might be the best approach.  I can just write a loop that at each iteration asks the user to manually update parameters that are stored in a text file, then reads in the new parameters from the text file, then runs my algorithm using the specified parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Your case is the perfect example for why the `mmap()` exists :)

[mmap()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) (available on all modern platforms) allows you to treat a file on disk as regular RAM, with "direct" random read/write access and OS-backed paging support (much like what happens to your memory when it is swapped out by OS's memory manager)

> Is there a way that I can keep this big matrix in memory while I change some parameters in my code then recompile my code and run it again?

Well, yes... But I have a feeling its implementation would be way outside the scope of your project. In essence this is what you'd do:

1. Create a "loader" that would load the data into memory and make that memory "shared" (available to other processes)
2. Launch your code, providing it with that memory's handle (or address, depending on your platform) so it can request access to it
3. When done your code will quit, detaching from that shared memory, which is still going to be held by the loader process for the next launch of your code

Comment: How fast is mmap() though?  If the data is still stored on disk, it seems like it will be somewhat slow to read into RAM (even if it's like twice as fast as other file IO methods).

Comment: `mmap()` is pretty much as fast as your OS's pagination. And since your matrix is sparse you won't be reading the *whole* file anyway, right?

Comment: This is helpful to know about, but I believe need the entire sparse matrix to be stored in RAM in order for my code to run fast.  The sparse matrix takes up several gigabytes of RAM, but I have a lot of RAM so that's ok.

Comment: This is exactly the thing - `mmap()` will (gradually) load your data as you access it and won't unload it back onto disk unless you run low on memory. The OS will even(!) cache it in memory for you between the runs.

Comment: @YePhIcK Regarding your first comment, you may be confusing Eigen `SparseMatrix` with sparse files. You need to read every byte of the file to get the entire matrix.

Comment: No, not confusing those. But you are correct - even for a sparse matrix I'd end up reading the whole file. Still would be as efficient as reading it as if it was swapped out and definitely more efficient than reading and parsing a "regular" file

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the data of your matrix in binary form -- just dump everything pointed to from `S.outerIndexPtr()`, `S.innerIndexPtr()`, `S.valuePtr()` (perhaps write all sizes at the start, if they are not always the same).

To read it again, just [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) your file and create a [`Map<SparseMatrix>`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map_3_01SparseMatrixType_01_4.html) from the correct start addresses.